# ComboBox database value doesn't refresh after Adding New Data

Tags: java, database, swing, refresh, jcombobox

After adding data into the database, there is no changes to the JComboBox unless I execute the program again. Do I need to call any specific methods to refresh the values? Thanks!

New Code:

```
 class ComboModel extends AbstractListModel implements ComboBoxModel 
 {
    // array? treeset? 

    public Object getElementAt(int index) {

    }

    public int getSize() {

    }

    public Object getSelectedItem() {

    }

    public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {

    }
}

final JComboBox stockListComboBox = new JComboBox();
ComboModel model = new ComboModel();
stockListComboBox.setModel(model);          

try
{
    // Database Stuffs
}

catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why the values you inserted into your database are not appearing into their respective JTextField after clicking the addButton?

Comment: `catch(Exception e){ }`  ***Don't ignore exceptions!***  Change that to `catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: @eabraham, After clicking addButton, the value is inserted into the database, but not inserted into the JComboBox (unless I execute the program again).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got second part of the question, however, regarding values added to DefaultComboBoxModel, you have to call a method to let the combobox know the model elements changed.
You can use [fireContentsChanged](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html#fireContentsChanged%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) method or fireIntervalAdded one.

Comment: please remove `You can use fireContentsChanged fireContentsChanged method or fireIntervalAdded one.`, then +1

Comment: Andrea Parodi, i've updated the code, is that the right approach? I've seen examples where variables are declared. Some are array, or treeset. What should I declare? Thanks

Comment: @mKorbel, what type of variable should I declare? Thanks!